# How to fit a function with multiple files in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

I would like to use the fit command for multiple files in gnuplot. 
I know that for one file the command is for example:

```
f(x)=a*x+b
fit f(x) 'file1' u ($18/-200):($4/200)  via a, b
```

Now instead of a single file I would like to have multiple ones ('file1','file2','file3'etc.) and find the best a, b, parameters that fit all data sets.

This question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586904/fitting-a-function-with-multiple-data-sets-using-gnuplot) but with different files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the question you linked, also here you must combine all files to a single one. You can use e.g. the command line tool `cat` to do this on-the-fly:

```
f(x) = a*x + b
fit f(x) '< cat file1 file2 file3' using ($18/-200):($4/200) via a,b
```