# Fit a function with multiple files and in different units

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

I would like to use the fit command for multiple files in gnuplot. I know that for more than one file, if the operation on the columns is the same, the command is for example:

```
f(x)=a*x+b
fit f(x) '< cat file1 file2 file3' using ($18/-200):($4/200) via a,b
```

Now instead of doing the same operation `($18/-200):($4/200)`, I would like to do different operations (because for example the files have the same quantities but in different units); for example, for file 1 `($18/-200):($4/200)` and for file 2 `($3*200):($7/400)`. The command

```
fit f(x) '< cat file1 file2' using '($18/-200):($4/200) ($3*200):($7/400)'  via a,b
```

that I naively tried does not work. Any hint?
This question is similar to 
[How to fit a function with multiple files in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384477/how-to-fit-a-function-with-multiple-files-in-gnuplot)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using bash commands, then you could use `awk` to preprocess your data:

```
# Get number of lines in file 1
n1 = word(system("wc -l file1"), 1)

# Create command to preprocess data
filename = "< cat file1 file2 | awk '{if(NR < 1+".n1."){print $18/-200., $4/200.} else{print $3*200, $7/400.}}'"

fit f(x) filename using 1:2 via a,b
```

Or generate a `temp` file within bash:

```
n1=`wc -l file1 | awk '{print $1}'`

cat file1 file2 | awk -v n1=$n1 '{if(NR < 1+n1){print $18/-200., $4/200.} else{print $3*200, $7/400.}}' > temp
```

and use it for the fit within gnuplot:

```
fit f(x) temp using 1:2 via a,b
```

Comment: I might misunderstand but gnuplot replies "invalid command" to both definitions of n1 and filename.

Comment: ...and the bash command gives "Badly placed ()'s" for the line n1 = word(system("wc -l file1"), 1) and "filename: Command not found" for the second line.

Comment: @Fred This is all meant to be executed within a gnuplot shell.

Comment: I don't know why but the reply is "invalid expression", on gnuplot 4.0.

Comment: @Fred gnuplot 4.0 is quite an old version (you should upgrade if you can), it is possible that system calls are not allowed or the `word` command is not available. In any case, you can just run the commands to generate a temporary file outside of gnuplot and then use that file for the fitting. Variable `n1` is simply the number of lines in `file1`, see edited answer.

Comment: Yes, word command does not work either. I just wrote a fortran program to do it. I'll update gnuplot. Thanks anyway for your help.