# Fitting Function with Multiple Files

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

My Data:
File 1:

```
2015-08-01 07:00    0.23    0.52    0.00    0.52    9   14.6    14.6 14.6   67  8.5 0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.6    14.1    14.1    16.3    1016.2  0.00      0.0   156 0.22    156 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.003   0.000   23.9    39  9.1 23.4    0.05    23  1   100.0   1   1.8797836153192153  660.7143449269239
```

File 2:

```
2015-08-01 07:00    0.23    0.52    0.00    0.52    9   14.6    14.6 14.6   67  8.5 0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.6    14.1    14.1    16.3    1016.2  0.00      0.0   156 0.22    156 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.003   0.000   23.9    39  9.1 23.4    0.05    23  1   100.0   1   1.8797836153192153  660.7143449269239
```

..... and so on.
So the csv. files are multiple days and from those days I created a scatterplot `using 3:43:0`
I used the `0`as a dummy so I could use varialble linecolors (if I wouldn`t have done that the colors would have repeated themselfs after line 9)

The Scatter Plot looks great but now I want to fit a curve into the plot. There are 2 similar questions: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586904/fitting-a-function-with-multiple-data-sets-using-gnuplot) , [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384477/how-to-fit-a-function-with-multiple-files-in-gnuplot) covering the Fit Data from multiple files but when trying the `cat` or `awk` command I always end up with an error telling me `cannot create pipe for data`
So what I tried was:

```
fit f(x) '< cat file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv file4.csv file5.csv' u 3:43:0 a,b
```

am I missing something here?
Cou8ld this be a OS Problem? I run Windows 7.

Comment: `cat` is an unix-command. I think the windows equivalent is `type`. For example: `fit f(x) '< type file1 file2' u 3:43:0 via a,b`

Comment: Thanks, don`t know why google didn't help me there

Comment: That solved my probelm thank you, i don't think I can mark your commetn as answear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `cat` and `awk` are Unix-commands. The windows-equivalent of `cat` is `type`. For instance, the following should work:

```
fit f(x) '< type file1.csv file2.csv' u 3:43:0 via a,b
```

If, for some reason, you need to use a tool like `gawk` (gnu-equivalent to `awk`), `grep`, or `sed` in windows, take a look at [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html).